# Opencart installation blank page after database configuration

Tags: php, installation, opencart

I have a problem with getting opencart to work. Everything was good on my localhost, but when I am trying to install it on my clients server, I get a blank page after the third part, which is database configuration. Any ideas why can this happen?

Comment: what is  your server OS? enable debugging and try again.

Comment: Have you tried to reupload files, some times a file may get corrupted when you upload it via ftp. Also other than that confirm php version used and see if your server has the minimum requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue with one of my client.

The most common issue is "Misconfiguraion of path in config.php" in root folder.

Double check the path in config.php

Another issue could be the user.check If you have added the user into db...

Answer (score 0):

Check for .htaccess file in root directory.. and see if any misconfiguration present.
I have installed WordPress earlier and then installed opencart so WordPress config was present in .htaccess